# Vue Router link Ana Router exact in children

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

there are two components `Dashboard` and `Apps` and they have `children`. What I want to do is, when clicking any of the Main Components
`showMenu` is showing but,
I don't want the main components to be opened. and I want the main components and active class to be written

I want it to act as `Dashboard` and `Apps`self

app.vue

```
<template>
        <router-link :to="{name:'dashboard'}" @click="isShow('dashboard')">Dashboard</router-link>
        <router-link :to="{name:'apps'}" @click="isShow('apps')">Apps</router-link>

        <div class="children">
                <div class="dashboard" v-show="showName ==='dashboard' && showMenu">
                        <router-link exact :to="{name:'home'}">Home</router-link>
                        <router-link exact :to="{name:'about'}">About</router-link>
                </div>

                <div class="apps" v-show="showName ==='apps' && showMenu">
                        <router-link exact :to="{name:'setting'}">Setting</router-link>
                        <router-link exact :to="{name:'profile'}">Profile</router-link>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
                <router-view/>
        </div>
</template>
<script setup>
const showName = ref('')
const showMenu = ref(false)
function isShow(name) {
        if (showName.value !== name) {
                showMenu.value = true
        }
        if (showName.value === name) {
                showMenu.value = !showMenu.value
        } else {
                showName.value = name
        }
}
</script>
```

router.js

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory, RouterView} from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/dashboards',
    name: 'dashboards',
    component: RouterView,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: () => import('../Views/home.vue'),
        name: 'home',
      },
      {
        path: 'about',
        component: () => import('../Views/about.vue'),
        name: 'about',
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/apps',
    name: 'apps',
    component: RouterView,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'setting',
        component: () => import('../Views/setting.vue'),
        name: 'setting',
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        component: () => import('../Views/profile.vue'),
        name: 'profile',
      },
    ]
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  linkActiveClass: "item-active",
  linkExactActiveClass: "exact-active",
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})
export default router;
```

Comment: This is really bad description. `I don't want the main components to be opened` but we don't know which of the components are main and which are not. If you don't want them to be opened - then don't open them. Or explicitly/forcibly close them. `I want the main components and active class to be written` - well, what prevents you from writing them? `I want it to act as "Dashboard" and "App" sself` - how do they act self? We don't know that.

Comment: my english may be very bad but what i want to do is just `dashboard` and `apps` specify them `target="self"

Comment: Well, have you tried adding `target="_self"` parameter to the relevant `router-link`s ?

Comment: what i want to do is when clicking name =`dashboards` and `apps`
I want `item-active` added to them. and I want it to dropdown when clicked on these 2 routers.

Comment: Have you tried `:class="{'item-active': showName ==='dashboard' && showMenu}"` ?

Comment: sorry i posted wrong :S

Comment: `<router-link :to="{name:'dashboard'}" @click="isShow('dashboard')">Dashboard</router-link>` when clicked..
I don't want redirection to happen.just do a v-show. 

`<div class="children">`  When one of the router links in it is clicked, redirection is done. `:to="{name:'dashboard'}"` add class `item-active`

Comment: Don't use `router-link` for a simple `v-show` - use `<a href="javascript:" @click="....">`